# Firefox Live Bookmarks - how to manually create?

Tags: firefox, bookmarks

I need to manually create a Live Boomark in Firefox by specifying the URL myself.

There are no options to do this inside the Bookmarks menu or the "Show all Bookmarks" / Library window.  You can copy and paste existing live bookmarks, but you can't edit their properties (other than name)

Researching this topic points to instructions that are at least 6 years old.  The menu options they refer to don't exist in the latest version of Firefox.

Has this feature been completely removed?  Is it still possible with the latest Firefox?

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know there is no way to directly create a live bookmark from within Firefox. However, the following (not necessarily convenient) procedure should work for you.

Save the following HTML file to a local file on your disk:

```
<!DOCTYPE NETSCAPE-Bookmark-file-1>
<!-- This is an automatically generated file.
     It will be read and overwritten.
     DO NOT EDIT! -->
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<TITLE>Bookmarks</TITLE>
<H1>Bookmarks Menu</H1>

<DL><p>
<DT><A FEEDURL="http://feeds.com/users:1234/feed.rss" HREF="http://feed.value.cannot.be.overridden.by.user.com">Generic RSS Feed</A>
</DL>
```

(Don't worry that this doesn't look like a typical HTML file.)

Then edit the FEEDURL value. Don't bother trying to set the HREF value, it will be updated from the value provided by the RSS feed (unfortunately, this is what I had wanted to do).

Now you can use the "Import and Backup"->"Import Bookmarks from HTML" function of the Bookmarks dialog ("Show All Bookmarks") to add it to your bookmarks.

If you are uncertain, you can use the [ProfileManager](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profile-manager-create-and-remove-firefox-profiles) to make a new experimental profile to check if this works as you wish (I used it extensively while researching this question).

Comment: Excellent! I exported my FF bookmarks to see how bookmark folders were handled, and it's just the same pattern, with a DL surrounding each DT (folder name) and DL (contents). Whitespace does not appear to matter. Of course you can export, insert the DT's above into an existing bookmark folder, and import again.